# Speech to text to recognize only numbers

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text

I speech_to_text version 2.4.1 in flutter to recognize text in a mobile app. I was wondering if its possible to use a grammar, or in general to limit the input a user can insert with voice, because my app should recognize only numbers. And using the general recognition of speech_to_text I can't have very confident recognition of numbers.

Thank you in advance for your help

Sebastiano

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well, on different platforms speech to text gave me different output. On Android it was number, on iOS text. I suggest to have a function that converts text to number. You can have a map of valid values, if the number range is small.

````
Map<String, String> numbers = {
    'one': "1",
    'two': "2",
    'three': "3",
    'four': "4",
    'five': "5",
    'six': "6",
    'seven': "7",
    'eight': "8",
    'nine': "9",
    'ten': "10",
   
  };```
````

Comment: I tried this way, but the recognizer seems not very accurate with italian numbers. I often get errors like "SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_network, permanent: true", even if I setup the recognizer to work on device. The problem is I get better results with recognizing natural speaking than with small sets of words like numbers...